# Real-time collaboration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, real-time, collaboration

A friend and I would like to do some real-time collaboration with Eclipse. Does anyone know a way we can share the entire project? I've looked around and I can't really find anything but something called Cola, and I can't find anything more on that than a video of them using it.

We've already installed the latest ECF, so if we're headed in the right direction, what's next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions for Cola are [right here.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin)

Comment: Ah, we used that page in the past and couldn't get it to work. I'll check it out again. Different version of Eclipse, I suppose.

This may be a silly question, but how do you connect to a provider once ECF is installed?

Comment: the explanation does not work for me. e.g. the update site http://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/3.5.2/site.p2/ was not found. any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I'm here from the future.. I'm curious how I can connect to a provider properly

Answer (score 11):

I think [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org/) is what you are looking for.