# Android/Java : Group project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am looking for a method to work on a project with three people. We are developing an Android application and we will be using Eclipse. Is there an add-on/plugin available out there so we can always work on the latest version of the project?

Thank you

Comment: Its called version-control, try to have a look at Git, SVN, HG

Comment: This post might also be useful if you want real-time collaboration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134952/real-time-collaboration-in-eclipse

Comment: I'll look into Git. Everyone seems to like it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need version control:

**Centralised**

SVN

**Decentralised**

Mercurial (Hg)

Git

(there are some others)

Centralised systems give you revision numbers, so at r2098 this was the state, but requires you to be able to connect to a server (unless the repo is local), I like revision numbers but this debate is not for this answer. Decenratalised don't, it's like an undo button with syncing and merging features sort of. Everyone has their own history of the project and can work on that, they sync up later.

For SVN with Eclipse you want Subversive, go to help -> install new software -> select the eclipse update site -> collaboration and select everything with SVn or subversive in the name ('cept Mylin integration, unless you want that)

There's a good book called The SVN book, it's free (as in freedom, like SVN) and a good intro guide.

Add a comment if you want more info.

Comment: @FredDesroches remember to mark accepted. Also if there's 3 of you, SVN is probably a good way to go, Dreamhost provide it as a feature of their shared hosting, you can do it yourself, or use sourceforge (a good service!) and such. You might also want to read "the Cathedral and the Bazzar" by Eric Raymond (IIRC), distributed suits the Bazzar, and centralised the cathedral.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use version control.  There are A LOT of these available, but the most popular are SVN (Subversion) and GIT.  Both of these can be integrated into Eclipse using various plugins.  There are free resources you can use for version control such as GitHub and Google Project just to name a couple.